# Анимация clip-path в браузере EDGE

Tags: svg, svg-animation

Коллеги, есть такой пример

```js
[...document.querySelector('*[menu]').children].forEach((s, i, arr) => {
  arr[0].classList.add('active');

  function go() {
    let position = document.querySelector('.active').offsetLeft;
    let width = parseFloat(getComputedStyle(document.querySelector('.active'))['width']) / 2;
    let cord = position + width;
    document.querySelector('menu').style.clipPath = 'polygon(0 0, ' + (cord - 15) + 'px 0, ' + cord + 'px 15px, ' + (cord + 15) + 'px 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0 100% )';
  }
  go();
  s.addEventListener('click', () => {

    [...document.querySelector('*[menu]').children].forEach((s, i, arr) => {
      s.classList.remove('active');
    });
    s.classList.add('active');
    go();
  });
  window.onresize = () => {
    go();
  }
})
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  width: 100vw;
  min-height: 100vh;
  background-color: #272727;
  color: white;
}

.root-element {
  width: 100vw;
  min-height: 100vh;
  background-color: #272727;
  padding: 15px;
}

menu {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 25px 10px;
  background-color: orange;
  position: relative;
  transition: all .1s
}

li {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  cursor: pointer;
}

li.active {
  padding: 5px;
  border: 3px solid blue;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="root-element">
  <menu menu>
    <li class="li">Manu-1</li>
    <li class="li">Manu-2</li>
    <li class="li">Manu-3</li>
    <li class="li">Manu-5</li>
    <li class="li">Manu-6</li>
    <li class="li">Manu-7</li>
    <li class="li">Manu-8</li>
  </menu>
</div>
```

Вопрос...

Как такое реализовать в `SVG`, для кросбраузерности, так как `clipPath` в ***EDGE*** работать не будет...

Comment: а `...` работает? :)

Comment: @StrangerintheQ, а почему не должен работать?

Comment: в моем не работает https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#Browser_compatibility

Comment: У меня работает и везде.... И даже в `EDGE`

Comment: ну если у Вас заявка на кросс браузерность, придется учесть и не очень старые версии =)

Comment: В большей степени меня `EDGE`  интересует, пока его не перенесли на движок `chrome`...

Answer (score 2):

Я вот такое "накидал". Правда не на svg, а на div'ах). Если подойдет вариант - мелочи сам подправишь)

```js
[...document.querySelector('*[menu]').children].forEach((s, i, arr) => {
  arr[0].classList.add('active');

  function go() {
    let position = document.querySelector('.active').offsetLeft;
    let width = parseFloat(getComputedStyle(document.querySelector('.active'))['width']) / 2;
    let cord = position + width;
    const active = document.querySelector('menu').getBoundingClientRect();
    div = document.querySelector('.imm');
    div.style.top = active.top + 'px';
    div.style.left = cord + 'px'
  }
  go();
  s.addEventListener('click', () => {

    [...document.querySelector('*[menu]').children].forEach((s, i, arr) => {
      s.classList.remove('active');
    });
    s.classList.add('active');
    go();
  });
  window.onresize = () => {
    go();
  }
})
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  width: 100vw;
  min-height: 100vh;
  background-color: #272727;
  color: white;
}

.root-element {
  width: 100vw;
  min-height: 100vh;
  background-color: #272727;
  padding: 15px;
}

menu {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 25px 10px;
  background-color: orange;
  position: relative;
  transition: all .1s
}

li {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  cursor: pointer;
}

li.active {
  padding: 5px;
  border: 3px solid blue;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.imm {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: #272727;
  position: fixed;
  transform: translateY(-50%) rotate(45deg);
  transition-property: left;
  transition-duration: 0.2s;
}
```

```html
<div class="root-element">
  <menu menu>
    <li class="li">Manu-1</li>
    <li class="li">Manu-2</li>
    <li class="li">Manu-3</li>
    <li class="li">Manu-5</li>
    <li class="li">Manu-6</li>
    <li class="li">Manu-7</li>
    <li class="li">Manu-8</li>
  </menu>
</div>
<div class="imm"></div>
```

Comment: Тоже имеет право на жизнь...))) Держи `+`